# Magento2.3.1: How to display all attributes of product on a product page?

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.3.1, product-page

How to display all attributes of a product like default and custom attributes on a product view page at just right side to the product.

**Note: I don't want to display at tab or anywhere.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

First create new file at this path :

> magento/vendor/magento/module_catelog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes_productpage.phtml

code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table1">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More Information') ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Go to your theme folder

> magento/app/design/frontend//magento-catalog/catalog_product_view.xml

OR

> magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

file. Add these code to this file:

```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes1"  template="product/view/attributes_productpage.phtml" > 
    </block>

<move element="product.attributes1" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.demo"/>
```

Now flush all cache memory and data, Reload your product page.

For flush, run this command:

> php bin/magento c:f

You can see this:
[image]

Comment: This looks great, but i don't get it to work.. i have 2.1.18, can you help me with that? @Chirag

Comment: Follow this code step by step and you will solve your problem @PaulKuijten

Comment: i have it working, thanks!

Comment: Happy Coding @PaulKuijten !

Comment: Hi, Does this solution work with configurable products, that is, does it also update the attributes of configurable products when changing configuration?

Comment: Yes. It workes for configurable also. @Joso